# Can I run multiple logic app from single master logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Hi I have 16 logic app which load file from share point but I need to run all those separately.

Is there any way can I run all those 16 logic app from one master logic app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could, the logic app support create the "child" Logic App. Then you could call nested Logic Apps directly from Logic Appps Designer.

If you want to run them in parallel, you could choose Add a parallel branch then call child Logic Apps.

Firstly ,your child Logic Apps need to be set with `Manual – When an HTTP request is received` trigger. Then go to the parent logic app add an action and search Logic App, then choose the Logic Apps you want.

[image]

About the details you could refer to this doc:Azure Logic Apps: [Call nested Logic Apps directly from Logic Apps Designer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34129.azure-logic-apps-call-nested-logic-apps-directly-from-logic-apps-designer.aspx).

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions,please let me know.

Comment: @Sumon , if this could help you, you could mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run multiple child logic apps from parent logic app.

either using **logic app connector to call other logic apps or HTTP calls** for all logic app from parent logic app.